# Как запомнить, изменить и возвратить css свойства с помощью JS или jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Оно должно по нажатию на кнопку изменять значения css-свойств. Но последние 2 строчки вообще не работают.

````
 
$('a').remove(".button_menu"); // удаляю все кнопки из меню
$("<a type='sumbit' id='about' href='#' class='button_menu'>Назад</a>").insertAfter("div"); // добавляю кнопку "назад"

let about = documecnt.querySelector('#about'); // заношу значения css в переменную
about.style.setProperty('color', 'red'); // изменяю значения css

}```

Код не работает...в чём ошибка?
````

Comment: Никогда не понимал, когда смешивают js и jq.. зачем??

Answer (score 0):

Возможно потому что надо `document`, а не `documecnt`

```js
$('a').remove(".button_menu"); // удаляю все кнопки из меню
$("<a type='sumbit' id='about' href='#' class='button_menu'>Назад</a>").insertAfter("div"); // добавляю кнопку "назад"

let about = document.querySelector('#about'); // заношу значения css в переменную
about.style.setProperty('color', 'red'); // изменяю значения css
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: боже...спасибо большое!

Comment: @АлександрБухаров используйте IDE и автокомплит. тогда будет проще